# bringing two projects together

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a simple window application I am starting and I was given another file I would like to bring into the new project. How do I bring them both together to work as one file?

**New Project**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

**Other**

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace CaptchaClient
{

    public static class SampleUse
    {

        public static void SampleSolve()
        {

        }
    }
    public class CaptchaSolver
    {

    }
    public enum ResponseState
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: One file? Why one file? They are two different classes. Keep them in different files. Just copy the file in your project.

Comment: You can add the file using Existing Item

Comment: Both files do about nothing, so there'll be little to "work".

Answer (score 3):

[image: check this image]
This screenshots shows the how yo do he procedure

Comment: Cool, I'm not the only one that uses C# 2010 Express. Thought everyone decided to move on to 2012 since "newer means better."

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project in the Solution Explorer and click `Add Existing Item`. Then browse to the other class file. Once imported, you might want to change its namespace to the one you are using in your project.

Comment: thank you for clarification. By the way if i wanted to bring `SampleSolve()` to the button event in the first code section how would i do that? Or how do i call upon the class?

Comment: @Mr might you just be looking for a C# tutorial?

Comment: @Mr.1.0 `CaptchaClient.SampleUse.SampleSolve()` if you did not change the namespace.